# Bluetooth controller connects to Steam Deck but will not operate

Tags: controllers, steam-deck, steam-input

I have:

- a Steam Deck, running SteamOS Holo 3.4.8 stable
- a Microsoft Wireless Controller for Xbox One, Model 1708

For the months I have had the Steam Deck, I have frequently used these together with no issues. Now, however, the controller will connect but the Steam Deck (both OS and games) **does not respond at all to any buttons on the controller.**

I have tried:

- Turning off the controller
- Forgetting and re-pairing the controller
- Charging the batteries in the controller
- Disconnecting the Steam Deck from wired dock/peripherals
- Removing the recently-added microSD card
- Rebooting the Steam Deck
- Entering desktop mode and starting a game there
- Changing the Steam Deck OS to the Beta or Preview update channel

Many other discussions of Bluetooth controller issues describe the controller *disconnecting*, perhaps due to RF interference. In my case, it is connected — both the Steam Deck settings and the controller's light agree that it is connected — but has no effect.

How can I get the controller to be usable again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally seems to have worked, at least for now, is:

1. In Bluetooth settings, *Forget* the controller.
2. Reboot.
3. Re-pair the controller, **only after rebooting.**

However, it's possible that some of the previous attempted fixes also influenced the situation.